# Mark as false positive

Tags: c#, sonarlint

how can I mark a false positive in Sonarmint? Adding just `//NOSONAR` was not working for me.

`((IClientChannel)channel).Close();`

It's saying I should review this cast because there's no type in this project that implements both interfaces. That's clear as `IClientChannel` comes from `System.ServiceModel.IClientChannel` and `channel` is my WCF channel.

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is in fact "How to suppress compiler/analysis warnings in Visual Studio" because SonarLint embeds its own SonarAnalyzer for C# and VB.Net which rely on Roslyn. And one way is to use the `#pragma warnings`preprocessor directive : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/441722ys.aspx